# Datatable onclick executes custom function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, datatable, datatables

I have an app with React, Spring and Datatables (my requirement). I can extract info based on the clicked row. My table is a separate component that is a child to every other component which needs a table (they just pass the appropriate columns and data in props and it works). Now I would like to have a function that updates the state of a parent component when clicked on the table row. In my Table component I create something like this:

```
updateIndex = (index) => {
         this.props.updateSelectedIndex(index);
     }
```

and then:

```
componentDidMount() {
        var table = $(this.refs.main).DataTable({
            dom: '<"data-table-wrapper"t>',
            data: this.props.data,
            columns: this.props.columns,
            ordering: false,
            select: 'single'
        });
        $(this.refs.main).on('click', 'tr', function () {
            var index = table.row(this).index();
            item = table.row(this).data()
            updateIndex(index);
            console.log(index)
            console.log(item)
        });
    }
```

But it says my function is not a function and all that. I get it there should be a problem with "this" but I don't know how to make my function recognizeable inside

```
 $(this.refs.main).on('click', 'tr', function () {

}
```

Comment: you can try to create "var that = this" and then call that.updateIndex()

Comment: The quick fix is to replace `function()` with `() =>` however you're not supposed to use jQuery with React. Look for a proper react datatable library.